Nginx Configuration Error After Setting Up SSL Certificate
I'm encountering issues with my Nginx server after configuring an SSL certificate. The server seems to work fine without SSL, but once I implement the certificate, I'm unable to access the website. Here's what I've done so far:

Installed Certbot and obtained the SSL certificate.
Updated the Nginx configuration file with the certificate paths.
Restarted the Nginx service.

However, when I try to access the site via HTTPS, I receive a "403 Forbidden" error. I've checked the file permissions and they seem correct. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance! F.C

Step 1 in troubleshooting anything, or at most step 1.1, is look at the log file(s)
